# Yandex Tank как установить через docker

Tags: python, яндекс-танк

брал за пример https://github.com/yandex/yandex-tank/blob/master/docker/Dockerfile

Dockerfile

```
FROM ubuntu:focal

ARG BRANCH=master

RUN export DEBIAN_FRONTEND=noninteractive && \
    apt-get update -q && \
    apt-get install --no-install-recommends -yq \
        sudo     \
        vim      \
        wget     \
        curl     \
        less     \
        iproute2 \
        software-properties-common \
        telnet   \
        atop     \
        openssh-client \
        git            \
        gpg-agent      \
        python3-pip  && \
    add-apt-repository ppa:yandex-load/main -y && \
    apt-get update -q && \
    apt-get install -yq \
        phantom \
        phantom-ssl && \
    apt-get clean && \
    rm -rf /var/lib/apt/lists/* /var/cache/apt/archives/* /tmp/* /var/tmp/*

ENV BUILD_DEPS="python3-dev build-essential gfortran libssl-dev libffi-dev"
RUN export DEBIAN_FRONTEND=noninteractive && \
    apt-get update && \
    apt-get install -yq --no-install-recommends ${BUILD_DEPS} && \
    pip3 install --upgrade setuptools && \
    pip3 install --upgrade pip && \
    pip3 install https://api.github.com/repos/yandex/yandex-tank/tarball/${BRANCH} && \
    apt-get autoremove -y ${BUILD_DEPS} && \
    apt-get clean && \
    rm -rf /var/lib/apt/lists/* /var/cache/apt/archives/* /tmp/* /var/tmp/* /root/.cache/* \

#RUN apt-get update && apt-get install -y python3-pip build-essential python3-dev libffi-dev gfortran libssl-dev
#
#RUN pip3 install --no-cache-dir --upgrade pip --upgrade setuptools
#
#RUN pip3 install https://api.github.com/repos/yandex/yandex-tank/tarball/master

#RUN apt-get install -y software-properties-common
#RUN add-apt-repository ppa:yandex-load/main
#RUN apt-get install phantom phantom-ssl

ENTRYPOINT ["yandex-tank"]
```

при установке

```
#0 53.53 Collecting typing
#0 53.57   Downloading typing-3.7.4.3.tar.gz (78 kB)
#0 54.96 Collecting grpcio>=1.44.0
#0 54.97   Using cached grpcio-1.54.0-cp38-cp38-manylinux_2_17_x86_64.manylinux2014_x86_64.whl (5.1 MB)
#0 56.28 Collecting grpcio-tools
#0 56.29   Using cached grpcio_tools-1.54.0-cp38-cp38-manylinux_2_17_x86_64.manylinux2014_x86_64.whl (2.4 MB)
#0 56.45 Collecting PyJWT
#0 56.49   Downloading PyJWT-2.7.0-py3-none-any.whl (22 kB)
#0 56.52 Processing /tmp/pip-req-build-93o5zww4/netort
#0 56.65     ERROR: Command errored out with exit status 1:
#0 56.65      command: /usr/bin/python3 -c 'import sys, setuptools, tokenize; sys.argv[0] = '"'"'/tmp/pip-install-0y5pi0zo/netort/setup.py'"'"'; __file__='"'"'/tmp/pip-install-0y5pi0zo/netort/setup.py'"'"';f=getattr(tokenize, '"'"'open'"'"', open)(__file__);code=f.read().replace('"'"'\r\n'"'"', '"'"'\n'"'"');f.close();exec(compile(code, __file__, '"'"'exec'"'"'))' egg_info --egg-base /tmp/pip-install-0y5pi0zo/netort/pip-egg-info
#0 56.65          cwd: /tmp/pip-install-0y5pi0zo/netort/
#0 56.65     Complete output (5 lines):
#0 56.65     Traceback (most recent call last):
#0 56.65       File "<string>", line 1, in <module>
#0 56.65       File "/usr/lib/python3.8/tokenize.py", line 392, in open
#0 56.65         buffer = _builtin_open(filename, 'rb')
#0 56.65     FileNotFoundError: [Errno 2] No such file or directory: '/tmp/pip-install-0y5pi0zo/netort/setup.py'
#0 56.65     ----------------------------------------
#0 56.81 ERROR: Command errored out with exit status 1: python setup.py egg_info Check the logs for full command output.
------
failed to solve: executor failed running [/bin/sh -c export DEBIAN_FRONTEND=noninteractive &&     apt-get update &&     apt-get install -yq --no-install-recommends ${BUILD_DEPS} &&     pip3 install --upgrade setuptools &&     pip3 install --upgrade pip &&     pip3 install https://api.github.com/repos/yandex/yandex-tank/tarball/${BRANCH} &&     apt-get autoremove -y ${BUILD_DEPS} &&     apt-get clean &&     rm -rf /var/lib/apt/lists/* /var/cache/apt/archives/* /tmp/* /var/tmp/* /root/.cache/* ENTRYPOINT ["yandex-tank"]]: exit code: 1
➜
```